# How to Map this Array of objects to get a new array of geos from each products items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to get a new array from this products object, of all the geos inside itmes property.  how i can do that?

```
"products":[{"code":"realestate","currency":"ILS","percentage":1,"totalWorth":150000,"totalYieldPer":0,"items":[{"name":"הבית שלנו בחיפה ","currency":"NIS","geo":"ישראל","worth":150000,"portfolioPer":0.022,"yield":0,"yieldPer":0},{"name":"הבית שלנו בארהבב","currency":"USD","geo":"ארהב","worth":5261700,"portfolioPer":0.761,"yield":0,"yieldPer":0},{"name":"דירהב אירופה","currency":"NIS","geo":"אירופה","worth":5261700,"portfolioPer":0.761,"yield":0,"yieldPer":0}]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/flatmap) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map):

```js
const obj = {
    "products": [{
            "code": "realestate",
            "currency": "ILS",
            "percentage": 1,
            "totalWorth": 150000,
            "totalYieldPer": 0,
            "items": [{
                    "name": "הבית שלנו בחיפה ",
                    "currency": "NIS",
                    "geo": "ישראל",
                    "worth": 150000,
                    "portfolioPer": 0.022,
                    "yield": 0,
                    "yieldPer": 0
                }, {
                    "name": "הבית שלנו בארהבב",
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "geo": "ארהב",
                    "worth": 5261700,
                    "portfolioPer": 0.761,
                    "yield": 0,
                    "yieldPer": 0
                }, {
                    "name": "דירהב אירופה",
                    "currency": "NIS",
                    "geo": "אירופה",
                    "worth": 5261700,
                    "portfolioPer": 0.761,
                    "yield": 0,
                    "yieldPer": 0
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "items": [{ "geo": "Some other geo" }]
        }
    ]
};

const result = obj.products.flatMap(({ items }) => items).map(({ geo }) => geo);

console.log(result);
```

I'm assuming that your source object contains more than one item in the `products` array, so I added one for the example.